# Only Short Paragraphs Floating

Tags: css, css-float

I have a page with several floated elements that is causing weird behavior on the paragraph elements.  That is, only the very short (less than screen-width) paragraphs are floating right.  Anything longer and the paragraphs ger pushed down.  Here is the page in question:

http://staging.pacificlean.net/about-pacificlean/pacificlean-of-washington/

The elements on the page are:

Heading (Floated Left)

Sub-Page Link Box (Floated Right)

Content Paragraphs (Floated Left)

As you can see on the page, only the first paragraph is floating (under the heading and wrapping around the sub-page link box) correctly.

I am really stumped with this, and as such, any help would be most appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Please post your CSS and HTML structure here, and maybe set up a jsFiddle. As soon as the problem has been solved, the link you have included (and thus the question) is rendered useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the rule:

```
.about-content p {
float: left;
}
```

This is actually preventing the paragraphs from floating up the page. As the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats) states:

> The outer top of a floating box may not be higher than the outer top
>   of any block or floated box generated by an element earlier in the
>   source document.

Comment: OK, awesome, that worked.  Thank you so much!

FYI, it also worked to delete the "about-content" div tag altogether.

Thanks again!

Comment: Well if you delete the acount-content div and leave everything else the same that essentially kills the `.about-content p` rule since the `.about-content` div no longer exists.